# BackupBuddy Plugin Error

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, backup

When backing up the whole site. This is the Error

-- Backing up with BackupBuddy v2.2.33...
15:10:14: Error #5445589. Invalid backup serial (9au6kfm0rj). Verify backup directory writer permission. Fatal error.
A fatal error has been encountered.  The backup has halted. --

Solutions from the support ->
Adjust permissions to allow write & directory creation access to your uploads folder. ie: /www/wp-content/uploads/

How can i adjust the permission? Any idea please?

Comment: Error #4344443: Backup failureError #9002: Unable to create temporary storage directory (/home/ironwill/public_html/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_temp/fba4d4z8fg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have FTP access to your site? If you access it with an FTP program like Filezilla or SmartFTP you should be able to browse to the uploads folder and right-click to bring up the options and change the permissions.

If you don't have your FTP details or have issues accessing that then the best bet is probably to email your webhost with the above information and ask can they change the permissions for you on that folder.

Comment: Thanks on this.. Sorry for the late confirmation but the problem was solved by changing the permissions..